# How to give jar file output back to ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, jar, processbuilder

I am executing a simple jar file by using process builder. The jar file simply computes the square of a number by asking the user to enter a number. I can enter a number at console but the program hangs. How can I pass this (number) back to process builder for its square to be computed by the jar file?

Here is my code for this:

```
public static void executeSystemCommand(String... args) {
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);           
    Process proc = pb.start();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());

    int ch;
    while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) ch);    
    }

    reader.close();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int k = scan.nextInt();
    proc.getOutputStream().write(k);
    proc.getOutputStream().close();

    while ((ch = reader.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) ch);    
    }

    reader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(-1);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to build the most complex program used to compute the square of a number? Why do you need to execute another process to do that?

Comment: Answer the simple question first if you can then I will solve the difficult one myself ;) by using that logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that inputs a string b to the jar file and returns an arraylist of booleans on the basis of output received from the jar file.

```
public ArrayList<Boolean> pro(String b) throws IOException, Exception {
        ArrayList<Boolean> ar = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar",
                    "myjar.jar");

            pb.directory(new File("path to myjar"));
            Process proc = pb.start();

            Scanner in = new Scanner(proc.getInputStream());
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());

            // Read user input
            out.println(b);
            out.flush();
            String response = new String();

            // Read the response
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
                response = in.nextLine();

            in.close();
            out.close();

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(response);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String bol = st.nextToken();

                if (bol.equals("true"))
                    ar.add(true);
                else
                    ar.add(false);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ar;
    }
```

Comment: I know its pretty late, i have a similar requirement , how are you making the jar listen to an inputstream ?

Comment: In this case the jar takes input from the console and writes output to the console. when we invoke this jar inside the process builder then we need to listen to process input and output streams to give/receive input/outputs to the jar.

Comment: can you provide a sample code related to the jar ?How should i initialize the streams inside the jar ?currently i tried: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) inside the jar, but it is not working

Comment: I didnt understant how you specify input streams insidejar, could u give an example

Comment: Hey you don't have to specify any input streams inside the jar. Just write a simple program that reads/writes to the console and make its jar. Then by using the Process Builder in another program you can listen and write to the process input and output streams where the jar will be sending inputs and outputs respectively.

Comment: didnt get you properly, what i am doing now is after calling the processobject.start, i am writing data to process's outputstream using processobject.getOutputstream.write(). Is this the correct way ? as of now in the jar, i am reading using bufferedreader = new bufferedreader(new InputStream(System.in)). But still no luck, can you elaborate a bit ? i am a newbie to java thats why,thanks in advance

Comment: thanks a lot, i am trying it as we speak, i believe i would be able to retrive the data i am writing to the outputstream of the process inside the jar.

Comment: did you accidently delete your comment ?

Comment: System.out.println("Waiting for a word");  
    Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);  
    String b = input.next();  
    ArrayList<Boolean> al = new ArrayList<Boolean>();  
    al.add(true);al.add(false);al.add(true);  
       for(Boolean a : al)  
           System.out.print(a ? "1" : "0");

Comment: You can try the above code for the jar to try out the process builder example on this page. I have made it very simple. The actual code where I used had a jar which gives out a new Boolean array list for each new input string. And sorry for the formatting of the code above. :) Gud Luck.

Comment: You are welcome Parameswar. Good to know that I could help :).

Comment: suppose , while executing the jar by double clicking it, it prompts "Enter number". How can we make sure that when executing using procewssBuilder, we get that prompt ? or is it possible ?

Comment: You will not get the prompt in that case. The inputs and outputs of the program are directed on process input and output streams and you can manipulate them there.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://pastie.org/4602094) is some sample code I tried and got working.

The program launches an external process using `ProcessBuilder`. It also spawns two new threads to:

1. read `output` & `error` streams of the new process and write it to the program's `System.out`
2. copy everything written on the program's `System.in` to the `input` stream of the new process

This works well, but I ran into some trouble getting to stop the thread which reads from `System.in` to shutdown gracefully. I could not find a way to interrupt a thread blocked on reading from `System.in`, so I worked around it by setting the thread as a daemon.

Here are couple of good resources on these topics:

1. [Interrupting Java threads](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/interrupting-java-threads/5144546)
2. [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4)